# unexpected end of file error PHP & JSON Decode Multiple Files

Tags: php, json

Hi I am working on trying to get my app to load json files from a folder and decode to a database using the following code :

```
<?php

$con      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "json_map");
$response = array();
$res      = array();
foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\JSON_Files') as $filename) {$json = file_get_contents($filename);

if ($json != null) {
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    //$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
    //$ss=$decode["array"]; 
    //echo $decoded['number']; 

    if (is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) {
        foreach ($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems)
        //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 
            {


            $configurationItemVersion = $configurationItems["configurationItemVersion"];
            echo "<br />", "configuration_Item_Version:", $configurationItemVersion, "<br />";

            $configurationItemCaptureTime = $configurationItems["configurationItemCaptureTime"];
            echo "configurationItemCaptureTime:", $configurationItemCaptureTime, "<br />";

            $configurationStateId = $configurationItems["configurationStateId"];
            echo "configurationStateId:", $configurationStateId, "<br />";

            $awsAccountId = $configurationItems["awsAccountId"];
            echo "awsAccountId:", $awsAccountId, "<br />";

            $configurationItemStatus = $configurationItems["configurationItemStatus"];
            echo "configurationItemStatus:", $configurationItemStatus, "<br />";

            $resourceId = $configurationItems["resourceId"];
            echo "resourceId:", $resourceId, "<br />";

            $ARN = $configurationItems["ARN"];
            echo "ARN:", $ARN, "<br />";


            $awsRegion = $configurationItems["awsRegion"];
            echo "awsRegion:", $awsRegion, "<br />";

            $availabilityZone = $configurationItems["availabilityZone"];
            echo "availabilityZone:", $availabilityZone, "<br />";

            $configurationStateMd5Hash = $configurationItems["configurationStateMd5Hash"];
            echo "configurationStateMd5Hash:", $configurationStateMd5Hash, "<br />";

            $resourceType = $configurationItems["resourceType"];
            echo "resourceType:", $resourceType, "<br />";


            $resourceCreationTime = $configurationItems["resourceCreationTime"];
            echo "resourceCreationTime:", $resourceCreationTime, "<br />";



            $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     configuration_item(configuration_item_version,configuration_item_capture_time,configuration_state_id, aws_account_id, configuration_item_status, resource_id, arn, aws_region, availability_zone,configuration_state_md5_hash, resource_type, resource_creation_time)



VALUES('$configurationItemVersion','$configurationItemCaptureTime','$configurationStateId','$awsAccountId','$configurationItemStatus','$resourceId','$ARN','$awsRegion','$availabilityZone','$configurationStateMd5Hash','$resourceType','$resourceCreationTime' )") or die("Insert Failed " . ((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
            ;

        }

        // check if row inserted or not 
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database 
            $response["code"]    = 1;
            $response["message"] = "successfully stored configuration items ";

            // echoing JSON response 
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row 
            $response["code"]    = 2;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response 
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }

}


?>
```

I know it will be something stupid like a bracket but even using an IDE I am still no seeing it

Comment: You have a missing `foreach` on line 7 for a start.

Comment: @Tim fixed that same error have added code again incase anything else didn't copy over correctly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the missing `foreach` on line 7 (I'm assuming a mistake, because it would give a different syntax error message).

Your actual syntax error is a missing closing brace. Add `}` to the end of your code before the closing `?>` and you have valid syntax. Whether you have working code is another matter. Try formatting your code with better indentation and you will more easily see where the missing tokens should be.

As a side note: A closing `?>` is not required in PHP and I recommend against it.

Comment: sorted thanks will heed your advice for future stuff